# Assembly Function Integer Local Variable

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

I'm trying to learn basic assembly. I wrote a simple program in C to translate to assembly:

```
void myFunc(int x, int y) {
    int z;
}

int main() {
    myFunc(20, 10);
    return 0;
}
```

This is what I thought the correct translation of the function would be:

```
.text
.globl _start
.type myFunc, @function

myFunc:
    pushl %ebp        #Push old ebp register on to stack
    movl %esp, %ebp   #Move esp into ebp so we can reference vars
    sub $4, %esp      #Subtract 4 bytes from esp to make room for 'z' var
    movl $2, -4(%ebp) #Move value 2 into 'z'
    movl %ebp, %esp   #Restore esp
    popl %ebp         #Set ebp to 0?
    ret               #Restore eip and jump to next instruction

_start:
    pushl $10        #Push 10 onto stack for 'y' var
    pushl $20        #Push 20 onto stack for 'x' var
    call myFunc      #Jump to myFunc (this pushes ret onto stack)
    add $8, %esp     #Restore esp to where it was before

    movl $1, %eax    #Exit syscall
    movl $0, %ebx    #Return 0
    int $0x80        #Interrupt
```

Just to double check it I ran it in gdb and was confused by the results:

```
(gdb) disas myFunc
Dump of assembler code for function myFunc:
0x08048374 <myFunc+0>:  push   ebp
0x08048375 <myFunc+1>:  mov    ebp,esp
0x08048377 <myFunc+3>:  sub    esp,0x10
0x0804837a <myFunc+6>:  leave
0x0804837b <myFunc+7>:  ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

Why at 0x08048377 did gcc subtract 0x10 (16 bytes) from the stack when an integer is 4 bytes in length?

Also, is the leave instruction equivalent to the following?

```
    movl %ebp, %esp   #Restore esp
    popl %ebp         #Set ebp to 0?
```

Using:

```
gcc version 4.3.2 (Debian 4.3.2-1.1)
GNU gdb 6.8-debian
```

Comment: in your C example, is your myFunc(int,int) supposed to not do anything with its parameters and declare but never use z? or is there a purpose for this function

Comment: The myFunc() function's only purpose is to declare the int z so I could compare it with to gdb's disas of myFunc() to see if I wrote my function correctly in assembly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your GDB is configured to print out Intel instead of AT&T assembly syntax - turn that off before it confuses you more than it already has.

The stack pointer (`%esp`) is required to always be aligned to a 16-byte boundary.  That's probably where the `sub esp,0x10` is coming from.  (It's unnecessary, but GCC has historically been bad at noticing that stack adjustments are unnecessary.) Also, your function doesn't do anything interesting, so the body has been optimized out.  You should have compiled this code:

```
int myFunc(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}

int main(void)
{
    return myFunc(20, 30);
}
```

That'll produce assembly language that's easier to map back to the original C.  GCC *would* still be allowed to produce

```
main:
    movl $50,%eax
    ret
```

and nothing else, but it probably won't unless you use `-O3 -fwhole-program` ;-)

Comment: @jtsan: The comments aren't completely right (`popl %ebp  # Set ebp to 0?` actually restores `%ebp` to the value it had prior to your function call) and changing the stack to 4-byte alignment can cause problems if you call other functions that assume 16-byte alignment (especially if they use MMX/SSE), but otherwise it looks reasonable.

Comment: The only other thing I would say about your original code is: don't write `_start`, write `main`, and return from `main` or call `exit`, don't do the system call by hand.  You want to let the C library initialize itself (or things like `printf` won't work) and hand-coding system calls is asking for weird compatibility problems.

Answer (score 7):

Depending on the platform, GCC may choose different stack alignments; this can be overridden, but doing so can make the program slower or crash.  The default `-mpreferred-stack-boundary=4` keeps the stack aligned to 16-byte addresses.  Assuming the stack pointer already suitably aligned at the start of the function, it will remain so aligned after `sub %esp, $10`.

`leave` is an x86 macro-instruction which is equivalent to `mov %ebp, %esp; pop %ebp`.